# Run MapReduce from MongoJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Is it possible to run a mapreduce job using [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs) in a node application. I realize that using mapreduce in the web server code is not the most efficient way to do this but it is for testing purposes.

Comment: I have written a post named [MapReduce in MongoDB](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/mapreduce-in-mongodb/) that shows how to implement Map Reduce using Mongojs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look at the following function definition in node_modules/mongojs/mongodb/lib/collection.js:

Collection.prototype.mapReduce = function mapReduce (map, reduce, options, callback)